# Is this UC diagram correct?

Tags: uml, diagram, use-case

The question is about 3 use cases:

- Add medicine to favorite
- Vote for a medicine
- Read about a disease

which have to go through the use case **Get diagnosis and drug recommendation** first (you cannot get to them otherwise).

In addition, both **Add medicine to favorite** and **Vote for a medicine** enforce the logging constraint on the user.

[image: uc]

Is this diagram accurate and correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can access those functions only from Get diagnosis and drug recommendation then they are probably not separate use cases, just alternative paths of the said UC. If they require login, it may become an extending UC, however login is not really bringing any value and usually also isn't presented as a separate UC unless it brings some additional logic to the diagram (e.g. additional actor like some social media system).

Comment: Thank you for answering. You are right and I understand what you are saying. In this case, which is the most elegant solution that you would choose?

Comment: Remove the `Login` UC and attach constraints to the UCs where appropriate. Also `Register` (verb only) is no valid UC name. Use predicate-subject(-object) in any case!

Comment: @ister I wouldn't see how `Login` would be any kind of meaningful UC. Even for social media a login is not a use case but a necessary constraint.

Comment: @ThomasKilian what I meant is that if you allow a login through a social media (so for example you can log into your portal with a Facebook account) then login with a use of some social media page adds a new actor (FB API). So it might be *worth considering* making it a re-usable UC, which is an extension of those action that require login. It cannot be used on its own though as it doesn't bring business value as such. I want to emphasise it very, very strong - worth considering does not mean it definitely should be added. One should always weigh pros and cons.

Comment: @RazvanStanciu I would entirely remove Login, Add medicine to favourite and Vote for medicine. They should be clearly visible only in the Get diagnosis and drug recommendation US flows (so e.g. in activity diagram of this UC) but they are not enough to be promoted to separate UCs. I also agree with ThomasKilian that Register should be renamed to Create new account or something like that. Register can as well be Register a new medicine, Register for survey and plenty of other Registers.

Comment: `Login` will still be a constraint. The SN will not do the login for fun. It's a necessary burden to taken when trying to access what it really wants to do (say `post a message`). A UC is never a (reusable) function whatsoever.